# Why can't I include dynamic image_tag in HTML?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display an image in Rails with image_tag so it can dynamically change based on if the user has an avatar attached to their account, but I keep getting an error for 
`<% if resource.avatar.attached?`. It also states

"undefined local variable or method `resource' for #<#:0x0000561b852e6890>
Did you mean?  rescue"

I don't know what is causing this, what can I do to fix this?

**Error**

```
<div>
  <% if resource.avatar.attached? %>
    <%= image_tag @user.avatar, class:"rounded-circle" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag("fallback/default-avatar.png", class:"rounded-circle") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: `resource` is not defined. Perhaps it should be`@resource` where `@resource` is an AR object set in the controller? Please show paste the content of your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `resource` is undefined.

Just change `resource` to `@user`:

```
<div>
  <% if @user.avatar.attached? %>
    <%= image_tag @user.avatar, class:"rounded-circle" %>
  <% else %>
    <%= image_tag("fallback/default-avatar.png", class:"rounded-circle") %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But it's better to make helper like this:

```
module AvatarHelper
  def avatar(resource)
    if resource.avatar.attached?
      image_tag resource.avatar, class: "rounded-circle"
    else
      image_tag "fallback/default-avatar.png", class: "rounded-circle"
    end
  end
end
```

Then just add this code in your view:

```
<div><%= avatar(@user) %></div>
```

And it's good practice to make `alt` attribute in the `img` tag.